# I tried installing Lido on my local environment - ISSUE WITH DEPENDENCIES

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have this high severity issue, what do I do? Can I just ignore it?

```
@openzeppelin/contracts  <=4.7.2
Severity: high
GovernorCompatibilityBravo incorrect ABI encoding may lead to unexpected behavior - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-m6w8-fq7v-ph4m
OpenZeppelin Contracts's SignatureChecker may revert on invalid EIP-1271 signers - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4g63-c64m-25w9
OpenZeppelin Contracts's GovernorVotesQuorumFraction updates to quorum may affect past defeated proposals - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-xrc4-737v-9q75
OpenZeppelin Contracts's ERC165Checker may revert instead of returning false - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-qh9x-gcfh-pcrw
OpenZeppelin Contracts vulnerable to ECDSA signature malleability - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4h98-2769-gh6h
OpenZeppelin Contracts ERC165Checker unbounded gas consumption - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7grf-83vw-6f5x
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install @openzeppelin/contracts@4.8.2, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts-v4.4
```

Comment: I'd try asking the developers. Probably, you have to update more than one dependency. If you just want to learn I won't worry too much.